# Why do I have to remove const from MaterialApp if I use a theme?

Tags: flutter, dart

First, here is an example **without** using a theme. I can put `const` on `MaterialApp`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const _MyApp());
}

class _MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp( //  const
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Demo",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Next, here is an example of using the theme.
It is no longer possible to put `const` on `MaterialApp`.
Instead, only `Scaffold` has `const`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const _MyApp());
}

class _MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp( //  remove const
      theme: ThemeData(
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      home: const Scaffold( //  const
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Demo",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Why do I have to remove `const` from `MaterialApp` if I use a theme?
Does this simply mean that the theme cannot be determined at compile time?

Since I am only specifying the color, it seems like it could be determined at compile time.
For example, if it is text, I can leave the `const` attached to `MaterialApp` as shown below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const _MyApp());
}

class _MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Demo",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ThemeData` doesn't have a const constructor, this is because the constructor atually has an inner logic to change some internal values, if you want to use const you can use the other constructor `ThemeData.raw` but you will need to pass all the required values:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const _MyApp());
}

class _MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.raw(
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
        /// it will ask you to complete the constructor
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Demo",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

TLDR: for a const constructor to work you need that all it's parameters are const values but ThemeData is not.